# How to use SmoothDnD library in Plain JS?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use [SmoothDnD](https://github.com/kutlugsahin/smooth-dnd) libary.

All the example listed there are using React or Angular or Vue. I would like to use this library in plain JS. Is that even possible? Can someone guide me or show any example of how this can be used in plain html/javascript page.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The API documentation for the plain-JavaScript API is [*right there* on the page you linked](https://github.com/kutlugsahin/smooth-dnd#usage), complete with this example:

```
<div id="container">
  <div>Draggable 1</div>
  <div>Draggable 2</div>
  <div>Draggable 3</div>
</div>
```

---

```
var containerElement = document.getElementById('container');
var options = {};
var container = SmoothDnD(containerElement, options);
```

Comment: ... and I presume you just need a `<script>` tag for the `index.js` file inside `dist`.

Comment: I did try that. Added the index,js and above code. But it is unable the find the method SmoothDnD. Instead there is a method SmoothDnD.default(containerElement, options). Calling this method makes the items inside the ContainerElement draggable but I am not able to drop the item in any other container.